# Fluent Validation and Structuremap AssemblyScanner implementation. ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate, structuremap, fluentvalidation

How can i use structuremap and fluent validations assembly scanner to bind the validator to the nhibernate entity?
sr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(cfg => cfg.AddRegistry(new MyRegistry()));
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory());

//Configure FV to use StructureMap
var factory = new StructureMapValidatorFactory();

//Tell MVC to use FV for validation
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(factory));
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;

public class StructureMapValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
{
public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
{
    return ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance(validatorType) as IValidator;
}
}


public class MyRegistry : Registry
{
public MyRegistry()
{
    AssemblyScanner.FindValidatorsInAssemblyContaining<LiveReport.Domain.Validation.PersonValidator>()
      .ForEach(result =>
      {
          For(result.InterfaceType)
             .Singleton()
             .Use(result.ValidatorType);
      });

}
}
```

Comment: Just a note to be careful when specifying Singleton. If the validator makes calls to the database, then the connection that it uses could get disposed of in the meantime.

Comment: @vartan-arabyan, should i register all of my viewmodels(more than 100 in my project) individual? Gosh! please say no?